# vertical scroll bar of jqgrid not appearing in ipad

Tags: ipad, jqgrid, scrollbar

I am using jqgrid in my application with pagination. In Mozilla,IE,chrome,safari it's showing vertical scroll bar to see all the rows in the girid.

But in Ipad it's not working. In ipad it's showing few rows (not showing the scroll bar to see the remaining rows)

I searched in the net some people suggest use the jqtouch. I tried that's working for div only not for grid.

Any one can help me to show the vertical scroll bar in ipad for jqgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad's Mobile Safari browser does not render scroll bars, as noted here: [jqGrid - Scrollbar missing on Safari Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150852/jqgrid-scrollbar-missing-on-safari-mobile)

Since you are using pagination, you might be able to work around this problem by limiting the number of rows on a page. For example, if the iPad grid can only show 5 rows at a time, then  limit each page to 5 rows if the user is browsing with Mobile Safari. That way there is no need for a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set jqgrid to auto-adjust height based on rows.
Try height: 'auto'.

Refer [jqgrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) for more.